# Angular js access associated controller from within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With HTML like this...

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="inControl">
        I like to drink {{drink}}<br>
        <input my-dir ng-model="drink"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript like this...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('inControl', function($scope) {
    $scope.drink = 'water';
});

app.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            // why is this logging undefined?
            console.log(ctrl);

        }
    };
});
```

Why can I not access the controller from within my directive? Why is my call to `ctrl` giving me undefined?

---

EDIT: add demo...

### Fiddle available here: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/VE9dX/

Comment: What do you want to access from the controller? You have access to the `scope`?

Comment: @tymeJV - I want to access `ctrl.$modelView`

Comment: http://jsbin.com/neka/1/edit?html,js,console,output I added the controller property to the directive and it appears to be working for me. I prefer jsbin over jsfiddle

Comment: Not getting any errors in my console on that fiddle. Works fine.

Comment: Think I got it... need to add `require: 'ngModel',` to return object

Answer (score 1):

see multiple controller can be attached with one app and simillarly multiple directive can be attached with one app, so if you wants to use one controller in one directive than you can set the controller property of directive to the name of the controller you wants yo attach with like in your case

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'inControl'

        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            // why is this logging undefined?
            console.log(ctrl);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Looks like it makes sense, but does not work for me - I still get undefined for `ctrl` inside function.

Comment: As I mentioned in last comment - I think I solved with... `require: 'ngModel'`

Answer (score 1):

Despite this working with `require:ngModel`, this still isn't the best approach as it ties the directive directly to the controller.  If you want your directive to communicate with your controller, you could be setting and reading off the scope.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="inControl">
    I like to drink {{drink}}<br />
    <input my-dir="drink"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('inControl', function($scope) {
    $scope.drink = 'asdfasdf';
});

app.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope[attrs.myDir]);
        }
    };
});
```

Alternatively you can use `my-dir="{{drink}}"` and read it as `attrs.myDir`.

http://jsfiddle.net/8UL6N/1/

Answer (score 0):

Adding `require: 'ngModel',` fixed it for me - not sure if there is another way to specify it...

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            // why is this logging undefined?
            console.log(ctrl);

        }
    };
});
```